# How to escape '@' in an ssh login_name with multiple credentials

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a multiple jumphost connection that needs to be automated and I'm currently facing an issue when I attempt to login.

Using expect works as intended, but unfortunately, I have to be able to login with just the ssh command itself.

```
ssh -l 'myFirstUser@my_second_user@<some-ip-address>@password_with_special_characters' server_1
```

This command with the password in logins argument gets rejectd if the password contains the @ character. using '' doesn't seem to fix the issue neither.

Is there a way to escape the character in this instance? Technically I can run the full command without the password and then get prompted, but since the ssh commands needs to be translated to python, interactivity is out of the questions.

Comment: What type of SSH jumphost server are you using? Interpreting the single username field as a series of @-separated fields is not standard behavior – it's something invented specifically by the SSH service on `server_1`, so the exact escaping rules (if there are any) also depend entirely on the SSH service.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that server_1 is a cyberArk sentry. I have never seen such configuration prior with @ to separate the login prompts prior to this specific environment.

Comment: Why not use a public key identification rather?

Comment: You might be able to use the URL-encoded version of the `@` sign: `%40`.

Comment: URL encoding unfortunately doesn't work as I have already tried %40
As for key identification instead of passwords, thing is it's the client's environment.
I ended up requesting a password reset, as I couldn't find a workaround to CyberArk's prompts/character escaping.